# Alamofire HTTPS request failing

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I want to use Alamofire in my swift application, to get the data from server. But when I am sending request through Alamofire its always throwing an error. But if I'm using NSUrlSession with default configuration it's working.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31945078/how-to-connect-to-self-signed-servers-using-alamofire-1-3) solution but still its not working

Code which I am using

```
let headers = [
        "Authorization": validationHeader
    ]

    let completeUrl = kReserveBaseURL + strMyResURL
    Alamofire.request(.GET, completeUrl, headers: headers)
        .response { request, response, data, error in
            debugPrint(error)
            debugPrint(response)
    }
```

Below are the issues which I'm getting

```
    Some : Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “abc.xyz.com” which could put your confidential information at risk." UserInfo={NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=<SecTrustRef: 0x7ff0c22052d0>, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9813, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=<CFArray 0x7ff0c044b840 [0x10996ba40]>{type = immutable, count = 2, values = (
    0 : <cert(0x7ff0c22044c0) s: abc.xyz.com i: Verizon Public SureServer EV SSL CA G14-SHA2>
    1 : <cert(0x7ff0c2204770) s: Verizon Public SureServer EV SSL CA G14-SHA2 i: Cybertrust Global Root>
)}, NSUnderlyingError=0x7ff0c2302070 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1202 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=<SecTrustRef: 0x7ff0c22052d0>, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9813, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9813, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates=<CFArray 0x7ff0c044b840 [0x10996ba40]>{type = immutable, count = 2, values = (
    0 : <cert(0x7ff0c22044c0) s: abc.xyz.com i: Verizon Public SureServer EV SSL CA G14-SHA2>
    1 : <cert(0x7ff0c2204770) s: Verizon Public SureServer EV SSL CA G14-SHA2 i: Cybertrust Global Root>
)}}}, NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “abc.xyz.com” which could put your confidential information at risk., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://abc.xyz.com/Api/CheckIn/GetData?userId=0&BookingDate=2016-04-16, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://abc.xyz.com/Api/CheckIn/GetData?userId=0&BookingDate=2016-04-16, NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey=0}
```

Comment: can i see code snippet you are using to hit the request?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are getting this error due to iOS security restricitons (Untruster server certificate on the SSL level). I would recommend to troubleshoot this by adding security exception into you app's info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
</dict>
```

Source link:
https://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/

**After adding this you should not observe the error any more.**

If it helps, you can figure out depper using this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html?hl=sw

Especialy relevant section to you is: "Using the nscurl tool to diagnose ATS Connection Issues"

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the security restrictions. In the info.plist add these two comments,[image: see this image]