# Certificate pinning stopped working in swift 3/Alamofire 4?

Tags: ios, swift, ssl-certificate, alamofire

Certificate pinning seems to have stopped working in Alamofire 4 and Swift 3

This is my code

```
let pathToCert = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "certificate", ofType: "der")
let localCertificate = NSData(contentsOfFile: pathToCert!)!

 let serverTrustPolicy = ServerTrustPolicy.pinCertificates(
            certificates: [SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, localCertificate)!],
            validateCertificateChain: true,
            validateHost: true
        )

let myServer = "...". //string in format without https://
let serverTrustPolicies = [
            myServer: serverTrustPolicy
        ]

afManager = SessionManager(
            serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
        )

    afManager.request("https://www.google.co.uk", method: .get).response { response in
                //I get status code 200 here, which should NOT happen
                log.info(response)
            }
```

The certificate loads correctly, this is the certificate

[certificate printed inside console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ER3lq.png)

My problem is that I seem to receive status code **200** from **my domain** and **any other domain**.

I should not be receiving **200** from **other domains**

I was told that SSL certificate pinning should not be implemented this way in swift 3 / alamofire 4, could this be true?

Also, could something be wrong with the certificate?

P.S. I tried this code too, but no luck either :(((

```
let serverTrustPolicies = [
        "*.mydomain.com": serverTrustPolicy
    ]
```

Comment: https://github.com/antekarin/ssl-pinning-swift  try with this example

Comment: @BHAVIKPANCHAL does it work for you ?

Comment: yes it's work for me

Comment: @BHAVIKPANCHAL other domains are blocked? what response do you get for other domains?

Comment: what you get in response can you show me ? so i will help you.

Comment: @BHAVIKPANCHAL "All Response Info: DefaultDataResponse(request: Optional(https://www.google.co.uk), response: Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x17023cac0> { URL: https://www.google.co.uk/ } { status code: 200, headers {\n    \"Cache-

Comment: @BHAVIKPANCHAL the request should be BLOCKED because it is not my domain

Comment: you added the certificate in you project or not And if added then what is name?you have to generate certificate from developer account and add into your project then after you have used

Comment: @BHAVIKPANCHAL What do you mean "the certificate needs to be generated from developer account"? Please explain...

Comment: can you please try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31945078/how-to-connect-to-self-signed-servers-using-alamofire-1-3

Comment: @BHAVIKPANCHAL I have tried it, no it does not work still. This is my certificate https://i.stack.imgur.com/ER3lq.png

Answer (score 0):

```
let hostname = "YOUR_HOST_NAME"
let endpoint = "YOUR_ENDPOINT"
let cert = "YOUR_CERT" // e.g. for cert.der, this should just be "cert"

// Set up certificates
let pathToCert = Bundle.main.path(forResource: cert, ofType: "der")
let localCertificate = NSData(contentsOfFile: pathToCert!)
let certificates = [SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, localCertificate!)!]

// Configure the trust policy manager
let serverTrustPolicy = ServerTrustPolicy.pinCertificates(
    certificates: certificates,
    validateCertificateChain: true,
    validateHost: true
)    
let serverTrustPolicies = [hostname: serverTrustPolicy]
let serverTrustPolicyManager = ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)

// Configure session manager with trust policy
afManager = SessionManager(
    configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default,
    serverTrustPolicyManager: serverTrustPolicyManager
)


afManager.request(endpoint, method: .get).responseJSON { response in
    debugPrint("All Response Info: \(response)")
}
```

Comment: If I make this request: afManager.request("https://www.google.co.uk", method: .get), I still get status code 200 which is not good. :(